# Why machine learning algorithms like xgboost cannot be used in the production environment?

Tags: machine-learning, production-environment, xgboost

I am a data scientist and I have seen at my workplace that all the major production solution at maximum involves random forest.

Why machine learning algorithms like xgboost cannot be used in the production environment? Why is there a need of reproducibility?

Comment: You might want to consider to post questions like this on: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for everyone but in most cases you want to have a reason for a decision. You need to be able to convince your clients/your boss that this is the right decision/prediction. If you use neural networks or other black box models you only have the resulting prediction and if you are lucky also a confidence estimate.

"White box" models or models which can be interpreted are better, because you can point to specific features of a sample and say that these are the reasons for the resulting prediction. Decision trees (but not too deep) or simple thresholding belong to this category.

If I understand the concept of xgboost correctly, you train your new trees to correct the mistakes of the previous ones. This means that the trees are not independent and therefore difficult to interpret.

Comment: But we can always use the feature selection/importance function of every classifier which will tell you the important features and with that you can the analysis of the prediction to the client. Isn't it? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Gagan Yes, that's true. It is a bit trickier than the mentioned white box models but you are right, with the feature importances it should be possible to give similar reasons. I suppose this discussion depends heavily on the application you are working on. If it is e.g. a weather forecast it does not really matter how you got it, but it should be as accurate as possible. On the other hand if it is used to make decisions, some reasons for why to do it are probably necessary. And these reasons are either directly given by the model or you can construct them as you mentioned it.

Comment: @Gagan my personal advice (based on admittedly only little experience) is to start with simple models which are still easily interpreted and if you get some positive results, you can try a more complex model and see if it gives any improvement (at the cost of less interpretability). This does maybe not fully answer your original question, but I hope it gave you some insight, why simpler models are often preferred. The whole matter is very opinion based.

Comment: Thanks @Robin. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen xgboost being used in production lots of times, I've used it myself (in python and java workers) and I would recommend it if it gives better results over random forest for example (which usually happens).